# copiar archivo php

Tags: php

tengo esta funcion de copiar

```
$srcfile='C:\xampp\htdocs\imagenes\M1001.jpg';
$dstfile='C:\xampp\htdocs\imagenes-copiadas\M1001.jpg';
mkdir(dirname($dstfile), 0777, true);
copy($srcfile, $dstfile);
```

necesito que el nombre M1001.jpg sea una variable llamada = $imagen.jpg he intentado con comillas dobles, doble \, barra simple y doble barra para la variable \$imagen, y no funciona.

he intentado esto:

```
$srcfile='C:\xampp\htdocs\imagenes\$imagen.jpg';
$dstfile='C:\xampp\htdocs\imagenes-copiadas\$imagen.jpg';
 mkdir(dirname($dstfile), 0777, true);
 copy($srcfile, $dstfile);
```

pero no funciona

Comment: Prueba con la función [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php) `$srcfile = sprintf('C:\xampp\htdocs\imagenes\%s.jpg', $imagen);`

Comment: no funciona sale este error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'C' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp.......

Comment: ya listo era la comilla doble que tenia en ''C muchas gracias

Comment: Te lo dejo como respuesta con un par de opciones mas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que con las comillas simples se crea un *string* literal, dando la salida siguiente:

```
$srcfile='C:\xampp\htdocs\imagenes\$imagen.jpg';
// C:\xampp\htdocs\imagenes\$imagen.jpg
```

Si usas las comillas dobles, la barra invertida sirve de escape para `$` de la variable, dando la salida:

```
$srcfile="C:\xampp\htdocs\imagenes\$imagen.jpg";
// C:\xampp\htdocs\imagenes\$imagen.jpg
```

#### Solución

Puedes escapar la barra invertida con las dobles comillas:

```
$srcfile="C:\xampp\htdocs\imagenes\\$imagen.jpg";
// C:\xampp\htdocs\imagenes\NOMBRE_IMAGEN.jpg
```

Puedes concatenar con las comillas simples:

```
$srcfile='C:\xampp\htdocs\imagenes\\' . $imagen . '.jpg';
// C:\xampp\htdocs\imagenes\NOMBRE_IMAGEN.jpg
```

O usar la función [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php):

```
$srcfile = sprintf('C:\xampp\htdocs\imagenes\%s.jpg', $imagen);
// C:\xampp\htdocs\imagenes\NOMBRE_IMAGEN.jpg
```